# Delete curent item in a Javascript while hasNext-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script

I have read 10+ questions about deleting items in Javascripts loops but they don't seem to apply to my situation.

I have this code

```
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
 
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
  var childFolder = childFolders.next();
 //processing childFolder
```

After this I want to delete the current item (`childFolder`) from the array `childFolders`. The reason is that I am doing some work in a Google Apps script but it often takes too long and times out so I need to be able to restart the loop and only have unprocessed items left in the array. To achieve this, in every loop, I copy the content of `childFolders` into a permanent storage that I can restore on the next run.

Comment: `childFolders` is rather an iterator, not an array

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to stop the loop of the folder iterator, and when you run the script again, you want to start the folder iterator from the stopped iterator.

In this case, how about using "ContinuationToken"? When "ContinuationToken" is used, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved by the native methods of Google Apps Script. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

Please set `var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("###");`.

```js
// When you want to clear the token, please run this function.
function clearToken() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("token");
}

// This is the main function.
function main() {
  var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please set your parent folder.
  var numberOfLoop = 2; // The folder iterator is run every this number.

  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var token = p.getProperty("token");
  var childFolders = token ? DriveApp.continueFolderIterator(token) : parent.getFolders();
  var count = 0;
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    count++;
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();

    //processing childFolder
    console.log(childFolder.getName()); // This is a sample.

    if (count == numberOfLoop) {
      var token = childFolders.getContinuationToken();
      p.setProperty("token", token);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

- When you run `main` function, in this sample script, 2 folders are processed and the script is finished. When you run `main` again, the folder iterator is started from the continuation.
- When you want to start from the 1st folder iterator, please run `clearToken`.

#### References:

- [getContinuationToken() of Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator#getcontinuationtoken)
- [continueFolderIterator(continuationToken) of Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#continuefolderiteratorcontinuationtoken)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> It is the script in step 3 here ourtechroom.com/fix/… I have problem with. I changed it to add all files to an array first and insert them into a sheet in a separate step at the end but that wasn't enough. Hence my question.

> My issue is that your solution is a little too complicated for me. That is, I have a hard time applying your solution to the script in the link.

Do you want to retrieve the file metadata of all files in your Google Drive? If my understanding is correct, I think that the script in your link is a high process cost because `appendRow` is used in the loop. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) I thought that this might be the reason for your actual situation. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Usage:

##### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

You can see how to install Google Apps Script library of [FilesApp] at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp#how-to-install).

##### 2. Enable Drive API.

This modified script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

##### 3. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the top folder ID to `folderId`. If you use `var folderId = "root";`, all files in your Google Drive are retrieved.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the top folder ID.
  
  var header = ["parent", "folder", "name", "update", "Size", "URL", "ID", "description", "type"]; // This is from your script.
  var obj = FilesApp.createTree(folderId, null, "files(name,modifiedTime,size,webViewLink,id,description,mimeType)");
  var values = [header, ...obj.files.flatMap(({ folderTreeByName, filesInFolder }) => {
    const f = [folderTreeByName.join("|"), folderTreeByName.pop()];
    return filesInFolder.length == 0 ? [[...f, ...Array(7).fill(null)]] : filesInFolder.filter(({ mimeType }) => mimeType != MimeType.FOLDER).map(({ name, modifiedTime, size, webViewLink, id, description, mimeType }) => [...f, name || null, new Date(modifiedTime), size || 0, webViewLink, id, description || null, mimeType]);
  })];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [FilesApp of Google Apps Script library (Author me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp)
- [Files: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is the script in step 3 here https://ourtechroom.com/fix/list-all-googledrive-links-files-folder-to-googlesheet/ I have problem with. I changed it to add all files to an array first and insert them into a sheet in a separate step at the end but that wasn't enough. Hence my question.

Comment: @d-b Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue in my answer? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Your English is perfectly understandable. My issue is that your solution is a little too complicated for me. That is, I have a hard time applying your solution to the script in the link.

Comment: @d-b Thank you for replying. By guessing your actual goal, I added a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If my guess of your actual goal was not correct and that was not useful, I apologize.